# Create a string by appending lines?

Tags: c#, string

Is there a straightforward way to create a string by adding **new text** as **new line**?

I want to create a log-style text, for keeping events as so:

```
Something superb happened
Wow, that is awesome
Look, a super awesome event here
A little event there
Whoops, an error here
```

What I've found is basically.. nothing new

```
List<string> output = new List<string>();
output.add("Something superb happened");
output.add("Wow, that is awesome");
output.add("Look, a super awesome event here");
output.add("A little event there");
output.add("Whoops, an error here");
string finalOutput = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, output);
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use **StringBuilder**. It is pretty efficient.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.AppendLine("Something happended");
builder.AppendLine("Wow ");
```

might be more efficient that what you have if you do it a lot as it doesn't create lot of temporary strings.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) class instead.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("Something superb happened");
sb.AppendLine("Wow, that is awesome");
sb.AppendLine("Look, a super awesome event here");
sb.AppendLine("A little event there");
sb.AppendLine("Whoops, an error here");

string finalOutput = sb.ToString();
```

Note that it has a constructor overload that takes an initial capacity (as an `int`), so if you have an idea of what that will be, use that overload, as it will avoid expensive resizing of the internal buffer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use StringBuilder.

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sbText = new System.Text.StringBuilder(500);

sbText.AppendLine("Something superb happened");
sbText.AppendLine("Wow, that is awesome");

string finalOutput = sbText.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to efficiently concatenate multiple lines together into a single `String`. Especially if you do a lot of string modifications (such as appending lines, etc).

Example:

```
var output = new StringBuilder();
output.AppendLine("Something superb happened");
output.AppendLine("Wow, that is awesome");
output.AppendLine("Look, a super awesome event here");
output.AppendLine("A little event there");
output.AppendLine("Whoops, an error here");
string finalOutput = output.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use string builder and append

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
output.Append("Something superb happened"+Environment.NewLine);
output.Append("Wow, that is awesome"+Environment.NewLine);
output.Append("Look, a super awesome event here"+Environment.NewLine);
output.Append("A little event there"+Environment.NewLine);
output.Append("Whoops, an error here"+Environment.NewLine);

string finalOutput = output.ToString();
```